# Android ListView: Add non-clickable label

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

I have a list view and a custom adapter for it. It works all perfect but now I want to add something like a non clickable label, if a condition is true. But if the condition is true it should also display the normal list item. And this is my problem I don't know how I can add the label and afterwards the normal item.

I am a beginner and I tried a lot but I didn't get it.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView;
    if (position == 3){
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_date, parent, false);
        TextView date = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
        // set text
    } else {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_list, parent, false);
        TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.event_title);
        // set text
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) has a method called [isEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29) which you can override. You can use that to assign if the specific position is clickable or not.

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if (position == 3) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You will also need to declare that not all the items are enabled using [areAllItemsEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled%28%29).

```
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But another problem is, that I want show the label and the normal item simultaneously if the condition is true.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the label to appear beside the list when a certain condition is met you could create a label in the XML for the page and set its visibility.

eg `Label a = findViewById(R.id.labela);
a.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

put this in the "if statements" you have created to control the label and set the listview to display the value you want and make it clickable or unclickable accordingly.

```
lv.setEnabled(false);
```